# How do you get the device serial number in iOS 8?

Tags: ios8, device, iokit, serial-number

The method below used IOKit to get the device serial number but now with iOS 8 it crashes an application. Does anyone know of a work around for this? I have a large amount of corporately owned publicly available devices with enterprise applications that are not intended for app store submission and they use the serial number to uniquely identify the device.

```
CFTypeRef platformSerialNumber = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpertDevice, CFSTR("IOPlatformSerialNumber"), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
if (CFGetTypeID(platformSerialNumber) == CFStringGetTypeID())
{
     serialNumber = [NSString stringWithString:(__bridge NSString*)platformSerialNumber];
     CFRelease(platformSerialNumber);
}
IOObjectRelease(platformExpertDevice);
```

It crashes on CFGetTypeID with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

The console logs: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL

Comment: May want to show the code that is crashing.

Comment: Cursory attempts at Googling this do not seem promising.  Apple considers this a privacy intrusion, so they don't support it as a capability.  You might be better off identifying by user.

Answer (score 2):

It crashes because platformSerialNumber is nil.

As of iOS 8 Beta 5, the IOPlatformSerialNumber property was removed and the call to retrieve its value now returns nil.

Comment: Correct its IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty that is the issue